# Correct Pod Architecture while using NFS?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, elastic-stack, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I am using AWS EKS to run Kubernetes Cluster.

In that, I am using AWS EFS for persistent storage to store application logs. I have many applications running and I create a PVC for each application. I need persistent storage for the application logs only. Now, I need these logs in Elasticsearch also. So, I use Filebeat to do so. So, this is my architecture,

[image: Kubernetes Architecture]

I just want to get feedback on this architecture. Is this the correct way to do this? What can be the drawbacks of this? How are you sending application logs to ELK in kubernetes?

Comment: Why did you use EFS rather than the [standard logging architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) to send to elastic?

Comment: Daemon set for log collection is the way to go!